# Magento - How can I add a non-taxable fee to a taxable product?

Tags: magento

We are using Magento EE 1.12. We have associated fees with individual products that cannot be taxed, however the product itself can be. The desired solution will be similar to a custom option where the fee is included on the same line item as the product and included in the product's price and therefore in the order subtotal. The only problem with a custom option is that the fee is taxed along with the product.

We've gone through several scenarios but I think the most likely solution is to use a custom option, but after the tax has been calculated we will reduce the tax to the correct amount. We tax on the subtotal and shipping. We will have access to the amount of fees so we can get the tax on that total and reduce the order tax amount.

Does this seem like a good solution? Does anyone have other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make it a bundle product, and put in a product which is not taxable.

Comment: Would that show up as two line items? We were going down that road, but creating another product for the fee adds a lot of hacking.